# Create a promise here, resolve it there

Tags: javascript, promise

I thought I had the hang of promises in all situations, but I'm stuck here: I'd like an animation to happen on a timer. The only thing I can get from the graphics package is the frame number, so I compute an end frame based on a frame rate estimate.

The graphics package is [p5.js](https://p5js.org), which exposes `frameCount`, that just runs up at about 60 fps on each draw cycle.  (I named it currentFrame in this question, hoping that would clarify).  As far as I can tell, this is the only visibility I get into the animation frame state in p5.js

```
doAnimation(duration) {
  // animation stuff
  this.endFrame = currentFrame + (60 * duration); // 60fps seems to be a good guess
}

draw() {
  if (currentFrame < this.endFrame) {
    // compute and draw the state of the animation
  } else if (currentFrame >= this.endFrame) {
    // animation done
  }
}
```

What I'm puzzled by is how to give the doAnimation caller a promise that resolves in the other method.  I've tried this:

```
doAnimation(duration) {
  // animation stuff
  this.endFrame = currentFrame + (60 * duration);
  this.animationPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    // I realize this is wrong, but it illustrates the problem. How do I run this test later?
    if (currentFrame >= this.endFrame) resolve();
  });
  return this.animationPromise;
}

draw() {
  if (currentFrame < this.endFrame) {
    // compute and draw the state of the animation
  } else if (currentFrame >= this.endFrame) {
    this.animationPromise.resolve();  // also wrong, I think
    // since resolve isn't an instance method of a promise
  }
}
```

Can somebody get me un-mixed up about this?

Comment: Is `currentFrame` a parameter of something? Of `draw`? Or is it really global?

Comment: @trincot - the graphics package exposes it as a global

Comment: What is the purpose of the promise? What waits for the promise before doing something?

Comment: Can you hook into the frame cycle that this package uses (probably based on `requestAnimationFrame`)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - the caller wants to start another animation after this one is finished.  So the caller would like to say `object.doAnimation(2).then( // do another`

Comment: How do you get notification from the graphics package that `currentFrame` has changed? Is that the `draw` function/method?

Comment: I'll add more exposition to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing the promise to resolve, you need to store the resolver to call:

```
doAnimation(duration) {
  // animation stuff
  this.endFrame = currentFrame + (60 * duration);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.onAnimationFinished = resolve;
  });
}

draw() {
  if (currentFrame < this.endFrame) {
    // compute and draw the state of the animation
  } else if (currentFrame >= this.endFrame) {
    this.onAnimationFinished();
  }
}
```

Of course you need to ensure that there is only one call to `doAnimation()` at a time, and that `draw()` is not called before `doAnimation()` (or more precisely, that `onAnimationFinished` is set up when an `endFrame` is set). You also might want to reset them (to `undefined`) once the end frame is reached.

Comment: Oh brilliant!  Thank you so much!  If I need more going at once, I could keep around a collection of resolvers, right?

Comment: Yes, you could, like a priority queue - each item a combination of frame and resolver, and `draw()` always looks at the head of the queue.

Comment: Heh, looks like my answer is no longer needed. Good point about keeping the queue in priority order, though you'd have to have a **lot** of active animations for it to really matter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, actually we should be able to assume that each animation in the `active` collection will do some drawing in each frame, so there's not really any overhead in checking whether the animation finished. But I don't know how (or whether) p5.js manages this, and what kind of object model the OP intends to use.

Answer (score 3):

In general, fulfilling or rejecting a promise should be done by the process that was started within the executor function you passed `new Promise`. It's very rare to need to fulfill or reject the promise from outside it (at least, in a way that the caller realizes it's a promise fulfillment).

I'd use a callback queue:

1. Maintain a list of pending animations which has the frame they end on and a callback.
2. Have `draw` look through the queue for animation callbacks it should call based on the (new) `currentFrame`.
3. Have the `doAnimation` code queue a callback

Roughly:

```
activeAnimations = [];

doAnimation(duration) {
    // animation stuff
    const endFrame = currentFrame + (60 * duration); // 60fps seems to be a good guess
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.activeAnimations.push({
            endFrame,
            done: resolve, // Or possibly: `done: () => resolve()`
                           // so this code is in control of whether
                           // there's a fulfillment value
        });
    });
}

draw() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.activeAnimations; ++index) {
        const animation = this.activeAnimations[index];
        if (currentFrame > animation.endFrame) {
            // Animation done
            animation.done();
            this.activeAnimations.splice(index, 1);
            --index;
        } else {
            // Continue animation
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for the `done: () => resolve()` comment is that in general, I try to avoid directly exposing the promise `resolve`/`reject` functions to code outside the promise executor, on the basis that code outside it shouldn't typically be directly in control of what happens to the promise. (I make an exception for `setTimeout`. :-) ) But that may be overkill here.

Comment: I see, thank you so much!  A design for @bergi's comment about running multiple.  Will use this if I end up needing multiple. Right now, they successive animations happen on different instances of this object.

Comment: @goodson - Sort of, I didn't think of Bergi's thing about making it a priority queue. I'm wondering whether this just ends up duplicating his answer (I saw his when I posted).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also assign to `draw` within the promise constructor callback:

```
function basicDraw() {
    // ...
}
var draw = basicDraw; // Default function

doAnimation(duration) {
    // animation stuff
    this.endFrame = currentFrame + (60 * duration);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        draw = () => {
            basicDraw();
            if (currentFrame < this.endFrame) {
                // compute and draw the state of the animation
            } else if (currentFrame >= this.endFrame) {
                draw = basicDraw; // back to normal
                resolve();
            }
        };
    });
}

doAnimation(1000).then(() => {
     /* whatever you want to do next */ 
});
```

Comment: This is very innovative. Thank you!